# Why the value of this expression equals false in python?

Tags: python

Why  the value of this expression “3==4 in [1,'123',3+4j,4 in [1,2,3]]” equals False in python?

In my opinion:

```
3 == 4 => False
[1,'123',3+4j,4 in [1,2,3]] => [1,'123',3+4j, False]
False in [1,'123',3+4j, False] => True
```

So, why the value is False but not True?

Comment: ...because `3` is not equal to `4`?

Comment: The expression is “3 == 4 in [1, '123', 3+4j, 4 in [1,2,3]]”，not “3 == 4”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of Python's [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

```
3 == 4 in [False]
```

is interpreted as a chain of comparison operators, and is equivalent to

```
(3 == 4) and (4 in [False])
```

See this with

```
'a' == 'a' in ['a']
# True
```